# CSS float margins between image and text

Tags: css, css-float, margin

Apologies if this is something trivial, but I can't seem to find a way around this.

So I have this very simple layout. 2 `div` elements floated to the left and one to the right. On the right there is an image, while on the left there is the text. At the top of the text part (also on the left) I want to have another `div` just a one liner, with a different background colour with the article's details, such as the author, the date etc.

```
   <div id="mainarticle">
       <article>           

       <div id="mainimgcontainer">
             <img id="mainimage" src="theimage.jpg" />
       </div> <!-- #mainimgcontainer -->

       <div id="mainarticle_details">
         <span id="by">BY JOE BLOGGS</span><span class="mainarticle_date">11/04/2014</span>
       </div><!-- #mainarticle_details -->

       <div id="maintext">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       </div> <!-- #maintext -->
       </article>
   </div> <!-- #mainarticle -->
```

The right column with the image will be 50% of the screen width. The rest will flow beside it and under it.

```
#mainimgcontainer
{
  width: 50%;   
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

div#mainarticle_details
{
  background-color: #f7f2e7;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dac397;
  display: block;   
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 23px;
}

img#mainimage
{
    width: 100%;    
    min-width: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    max-height: 32%;
}
```

Now, in order for the main text not to touch the image, I put a `margin-left : 10px;` on the image. However, This also puts a gap between the top `#mainarticle_details` and the image. I wish these 2 to touch each other.

On the other hand, if I add a `padding-right` or `margin-right` to just to the `#maintext`, it only applies to when the text is taking the full width, and the text still touches the image.

Is there any way to make the top `#mainarticle_details` touch the image, but the text spaced 10px from the image?

I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/A7uSr/29/

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention, this is intended for a mobile website. So it needs to work for varying screen widths. `fixed` positioning is also very buggy on mobile devices like the stock Android browsers (not Chrome) so keep that in mind too. This will eventually be the `landscape` view of the article (the portrait view will just have the image at the top and text underneath). For this reason the image has to be on top of the text, and CSS will just move it to the side when the device is turned to landscape mode.

I also added some more details from my real scenario which I realised will effect the solution. Mainly the padding of the containing `div` and the size of the image. 
JSFiddle also updated.

Comment: Was it your intention to close `div#maintext` after the first paragraph? Is it safe to assume that the additional paragraphs in your jsfiddle should be inside `div#maintext`?

Comment: Yes sorry about that... my mistake when I added some more text to demonstrate it better I forgot to move the closing </div> down.

Comment: I fixed it (new jsfiddle link included above). Also I clarified a bit why it is structured that way, because this is for a mobile web site.

Comment: Do you mind explaining a bit about what is intrinsically buggy with using absolute position on mobile sites? I haven't heard of that.

Comment: @showdev Sorry I was referring to `fixed` positioning on mobile devices which tends to go haywire especially on old stock Android browsers. I confused it with `absolute` positioning. Its a very famous problem... http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success by setting the header to `position:absolute` and `width:100%`. This allows the header to extend behind the image, making it appear to touch the image while the text retains a 10px margin.

I moved the image above the header in the HTML to avoid having to set `z-index`.

I also set a CSS definition for the image, making it respect its container's percentage width.

[WORKING EXAMPLE (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/A7uSr/13/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mainarticle">
    <article>

        <div id="mainimgcontainer">
            <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/specoalpurpose/micro/af-s_vr_micro-nikkor_105mmf_28_if/img/sample/sample_l.jpg" />
        </div>        
        <!-- #mainimgcontainer -->

        <div id="mainarticle_details"> <span id="by">BY JOE BLOGGS</span></div>       
        <!-- #mainarticle_details -->

        <div id="maintext">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Nam blandit lectus quis vestibulum blandit. Nunc viverra lectus eget tristique tempor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc imperdiet porta tincidunt. In vitae felis volutpat nisi pulvinar aliquam. Ut tempor sagittis congue. Aenean at commodo lorem. Ut faucibus tellus egestas facilisis dictum. Quisque eget mi et elit tincidunt porttitor. Pellentesque egestas libero sit amet urna sodales, non hendrerit lorem tempus. Donec risus enim, convallis in hendrerit sed, dapibus at purus. Vestibulum eu nisl at velit placerat mollis sed quis neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum venenatis at lacus a ullamcorper. Integer eget lectus id tortor bibendum imperdiet.</p>
            <p>Maecenas consectetur eros erat, quis pharetra nulla ornare eget. Nam ac risus porttitor, fringilla quam eu, cursus lacus. Cras adipiscing enim vitae leo dictum, at varius sapien bibendum. Quisque consequat suscipit purus, ac luctus ipsum volutpat ut. Nam fermentum tristique turpis. Sed semper orci et turpis placerat, non tincidunt est eleifend. Aenean a ligula eu libero facilisis scelerisque sit amet fringilla sapien. Aenean dictum ante orci, vel facilisis metus posuere ut. Maecenas sed odio ut velit tincidunt venenatis in ut lacus. Pellentesque condimentum tellus eu mollis hendrerit. Mauris adipiscing arcu ut fringilla aliquam. Nullam ultricies ac est nec cursus. Morbi vitae leo id nisi placerat tincidunt. Ut pulvinar, justo vel euismod aliquet, urna lorem feugiat metus, sit amet sagittis ipsum nibh quis augue. Vestibulum quis convallis turpis. Aenean fringilla ut nulla et laoreet.</p>
            <p>Nunc id nibh neque. Fusce ultricies quam vehicula elit dictum convallis. Aenean auctor, massa venenatis ullamcorper semper, ante purus vestibulum lacus, a ullamcorper arcu enim sit amet ante. Nulla aliquet vel lacus eu vulputate. Morbi elit metus, laoreet vel nunc at, consectetur pellentesque lectus. Ut blandit mi in odio sollicitudin, sit amet sodales lorem sollicitudin. Suspendisse lobortis urna sit amet faucibus posuere. Mauris cursus ac neque vitae malesuada. Curabitur a lorem ut nisi vestibulum scelerisque a id risus. Nulla mattis rhoncus congue. Quisque nec dolor nulla. Sed tempus nisl aliquam, pellentesque lacus in, faucibus felis. Nulla sit amet arcu rhoncus, blandit nunc sit amet, tincidunt erat.</p>
            <p>Sed vehicula enim velit, vitae fermentum felis consectetur nec. Sed sollicitudin vehicula leo quis laoreet. Mauris lobortis vitae massa id malesuada. Nam sit amet vulputate est, ut adipiscing orci. Quisque non sapien lectus. Nullam dapibus mauris non nisi lacinia, sodales posuere sem pellentesque. Sed tincidunt nibh id lacus rutrum sodales. Sed consequat elementum quam, sit amet tempus lorem ornare quis. Etiam sit amet aliquam ligula, ut feugiat ipsum. Nunc condimentum turpis nibh, vel faucibus arcu pretium ac. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris quis justo justo. Nam molestie suscipit velit, et ullamcorper mi laoreet in. Cras congue euismod odio, ut sagittis ligula feugiat sit amet.</p>
        </div>

    </article>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    position:relative;
    margin:10px;
}
#mainimgcontainer {
    position:relative;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#mainimgcontainer img {
    width:100%;
}
div#mainarticle_details {
    background-color: #f7f2e7;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dac397;
    line-height: 22px;
    height: 23px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
div#mainarticle_details span {
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
}
div#maintext {
    position:relative;
    padding:23px 0 0;
}
```

(As a personal note, I think it looks better to [keep the margin consistent](http://jsfiddle.net/A7uSr/18/) or to [put the header above the image and text](http://jsfiddle.net/A7uSr/19/).)

### UPDATE:

As you mentioned, longer headings were not handled well. If they were too long, they disappeared behind the image.

I realized that `position:absolute` was not neccesary. I removed it from the heading in order to allow wrapped, multi-line headings. The `width:100%` part keeps the header background extended behind the image while still allowing the header text to wrap to another line.

I also added a media query to demonstrate how the layout can change for mobile.

```
<div id="mainarticle_details">
    <p id="by">BY JOE BLOGGS AND A LONGER HEADING</p>
</div>
```

```
div#mainarticle_details {
    background-color: #f7f2e7;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dac397;
    line-height: 22px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
div#mainarticle_details p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  div#mainimgcontainer {
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
  }
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/A7uSr/40/)

Comment: The reason for the header being under the image is because this CSS will only work for `landscape`, in `portrait` the client wants it to be Image, details, main text, all underneath each other. There is an `h1` on top of everything which I haven't shown because its not related to the issue.

Comment: the problem with your approach is that if the contents of the article details are longer than 50% they will go under the image. This is for a mobile website, and in that bar there will be a bit more info, which might occasionally be longer.

Comment: That is true, longer headings were not handled well. If they were too long, they would disappear behind the image. Please see my update for a better solution.

Comment: Your approach is very interesting. I had a few things missing from my demo, basically some padding overall. Will your approach still work?

Comment: You mean padding around the entire page? Yes, it should still work. It gets messy at very narrow widths (less than 100px or so), but this can be solved by adding `min-width` to your container. http://jsfiddle.net/A7uSr/39/

Comment: Well it isn't around the entire page, because before that there is some more stuff... I have updated the question with the latest fiddle. You get my +1 in the meantime because it seems like a good approach.

Comment: +1 for the really nice mobile code, and working answer overall.

Comment: @showdev seems to work perfectly... cheers for the idea of the `z-index`!

Comment: @showdev I am facing something strange. When I tried to put it in my page, the #mainarticle_details is expanding throughout the page including the text, and ends up under the image (vertically not z-index-wise). What is forcing your text to stop when it encounters the image? I can't understand why it works in the JSFiddle but not in my page.

Comment: The "details" should wrap around the image in the same way that the "text" does. Possible to provide a link to your page?

Comment: @showdev No its still on my PC... but nevermind, I found what it was. I had an `overflow : hidden` which for some reason causes this. The moment I removed it, it worked like yours. Cheers...

Comment: @showdev By the way, I noticed a small issue when we have the right 10px padding of the `#mainarticle`, since the `#mainarticle_details` has a `width` of 100% it stretches beyond the image (if you have `padding` in it). I solved it by adding `box-sizing : border-box;` to the `#mainarticle_details`. Might be useful for people facing a similar problem.

Comment: In my code, I had moved the "details" padding to its `<p>` child. But your `box-sizing` solution sounds good, too.

Comment: In case you are interested, here is some information on why `overflow:hidden` stops text from wrapping around a floated element: http://red-team-design.com/how-to-fix-wrapping-text-around-floated-elements/

Answer (score 1):

### What's Going On

We need the `margin` of the image to not affect the header `div`, so we need to `position` it `absolute`ly. We also need to set the overall wrapper to `position:relative` to catch the positioning of the header. Finally, we need to add a `padding-top` to the text.

### Code

```
#mainarticle article {
    position:relative;
}

div#mainarticle_details {
    width:47%;   /* This could be 46%, but due to sub-pixel issues pointed out in comments, if you put 46%, some browsers will show a tiny break. */
    padding:0 2%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}

#maintext {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7uSr/37/)**

### Result

[image]

Comment: Your examples show the text and heading buried down the bottom of the page out of site and the image at the top? I'm viewing it on chrome windows 7.

Comment: That's odd. Screenshot shows what it looks like in Firefox.

Comment: Steven, I appreciate you pointing out the error, but now that it's fixed, could you remove the downvote?

Comment: Your update works pretty well. But I sometimes get a small gap between the header and the image, probably due to [sub-pixel issues](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/). The width of the header plus the width of the image should add up to 100% but, since they are percentage-based, sub-pixels are rounded and do not always add up to exactly 100%.

Comment: Guys, whoever downvoted him please remove it, because its the best solution so far...

Comment: I appreciate that, jbx. I've updated to address showdev's concerns. On Chrome, there is now no tiny break at all.

Comment: @AndyM, I just have a small issue left, which I forgot to include. I have an overall padding from both sides (now included in the updated question and JSFiddle). Your solution worked fine but when I put it in my actual context it overlapped a little on the image due to this. How would I compensate for this?

Comment: Fixed the mobile view by changing `width:50%` to `width:47%`, and setting the `position:relative` on the `article`. Still don't see why people think this deserves a -2...

Comment: @AndyM I gave you my +1. I only have one :). I am going to test your solution and showdev's to see which works best on mobile devices to choose the answer.

Comment: His has some mobile changeover code which is pretty much perfect, because I went to duplicate the effect and came out with almost word for word exact same code, which I don't want to steal since he posted first. I'd use it if you want things to look better on mobile. And thank you for the vote! Edit: Which happened right as someone else downvoted I guess. These are the days I wonder why I do StackOverflow.

Comment: @AndyM I hope the others remove the -1s. There seems to be 3 now! Well the mobile changeover code I already have, so thats not the issue, my page is pretty much there, I only had this annoying gap. Your approach is a bit different, he puts the whole bar underneath with the `z-index`, while you try to put it beside it as I originally was trying ...

Comment: The problem with putting it under the whole thing is that it's difficult to keep padding-right on the text, because the padding is under the image. I'd really rather do 46%, but as pointed out, on Chrome that leaves a 1px gap. 47 is the best compromise I can find.

Answer (score 0):

1). Your `mainarticle_details` is not touching image because of `margin-left: 10px;` in `mainimgcontainer`. Make it 0.

2). Once you do a float:right, it remains on top of whatever content is there behind it. That means, your `maintext` is behind your image. That means, if you don't want it to touch the image, add `padding-right: 52%;`. Why 52%, because image is taking 50%, so 52 will give some padding and text will not touch image !

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshcp/A7uSr/10/)

Comment: This is an interesting concept, but the text doesn't wrap around the image. It only appears to wrap because the OP (accidentally) closed `div#maintext` after the first paragraph. Check it out at a more narrow width: http://jsfiddle.net/A7uSr/22/

Comment: Yes, I moved down the `<div>` I had added some extra `lorem ipsum` text to improve the demo but forgot to move it. The updated one is here: http://jsfiddle.net/A7uSr/23/

Comment: @jaycp A `padding-right: 52%` will also make the rest of the text under the image also padded with white space. I don't want that.